# Why am I getting a run-time error on school server but not on big servers like HackerEarth or HackerRank for this minimum spanning tree code?

Tags: graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I got a homework where I needed to wright a program to find MST of a graph. I tried running it on the school server but I get a run-time error. On big servers like HackerEarth or HackerRank, however, I got correct answers on all test cases. The boundary for the number of edges and vertices is 100000 and for the weight of an edge 10000. Vertices are labeled from 0 to n.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Edge
{
    public:
        int x, y;
        long long w;
        bool operator<(const Edge& next) const;
};

bool Edge::operator<(const Edge& next) const
{
    return this->w < next.w;
}

class DisjointSet
{
    public:
        int parent, rank;
};

DisjointSet set[100100];
Edge edges[100100];

int findWithPathCompression(int x)
{
    if(set[x].parent != x)
        set[x].parent = findWithPathCompression(set[x].parent);

    return set[x].parent;
}

bool unionByRank(int x1, int y1)
{
    int x = findWithPathCompression(x1);
    int y = findWithPathCompression(y1);

    if(x == y)
        return false;

    if(set[x].rank > set[y].rank)
        set[y].parent = x;
    else if(set[y].rank > set[x].rank)
        set[x].parent = y;
    else
    {
        set[y].parent = x;
        set[x].rank++;
    }   

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int n, m, e = 0, c = 0;
    long long r = 0;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        set[i].parent = i;
        set[i].rank = 1;
    }   

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d %lld",&edges[i].x,&edges[i].y,&edges[i].w);
        edges[i].x;
        edges[i].y;
    }   

    sort(edges,edges + m);

    while(e != n - 1)
    {
        if(unionByRank(edges[c].x,edges[c].y))
        {
            r += edges[c].w;
            e++;
        }

        c++;
    }

    printf("%lld\n",r);
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting here ???

Comment: @ShowStopper I don't know, the only feedback I'm getting is RTE (run-time error).